# There is no group that contains a single element of order $\gt$ 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just want to make sure the statement I wrote in the title is correct.

I proved a week ago that there is no group that contains a single element of order 3. The reason is that its inverse is also an element of order 3 and they must be different (because both of them of order 3).

It seems like I can derive from this statement that there is no group that contains a single element of order greater than 2 (if there was such a group we could show the same contradiction as above).

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that would indeed be a valid proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is! In brief, $o(g) = o(g^{-1})$ and $g \ne g^{-1}$ if $o(g) > 2$.